# Apache RewriteRule losing one slash of the https://

Tags: php, apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

On my apache server, I need to pass full URLs as parameters to a php function. However, when I use something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../image.php?url=$1
```

$1 ends up losing one of the slashes of the https. So, in other words, if I try using it to parse https://example.com/img01.jpg, $1 is only receiving https:/example.com/img01.jpg

Comment: Where exactly are you using this rule? What other directives do you have? `$1` shouldn't contain the scheme + hostname anyway, the `RewriteRule` directive matches the URL-path only.

Comment: I have a php script that caches images. normally, you would access it as example.com/image.php?url=https://anothersite.com/img01.jpg , but I want the users to be able to reach it instead by going to example.com/image/https://anothersite.com/img01.jpg

Comment: And... where exactly are you using this rule? (Server config? vHost? `<Directory>` container? `.htaccess`? Where is the `.htaccess` file located? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files?) What other directives/rules do you have? There are some errors with the rule you've posted, however, for you to get the result you are seeing you would also seem to have a conflict with existing directives.